# kstat difference between bytes and bytes64

Tags: illumos

I recently started to play with `kstat` and I would like two write a simple script to graph the network usage of all my zones.

After some research I found everything needed under `link:0:::`.
I am primarily interested by the packet and byte count but these counters are available in two versions:

- `link:0:::*bytes`
- `link:0:::*bytes64`

and same for the packet count with:

- `link:0:::*packets`
- `link:0:::*packets64`

The packet count appear to be same but not the byte count.

Could somebody explain the difference between these counters and their 64 versions ?
Additionally any documentation or reference on `kstat` counters in general would be of a great help.

Note: moved from serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics suffixed by 64 are stored on 64 bit variables while the other ones are stored on 32 bit variables.

There is no difference with the packets counter as you haven't (yet) exceeded 4 Billion (2^32) packets on that interface but as there already has been more than 4 GiB transmitted, the values are different between packets and packets64.

The bottom line is: use the *64 counters when available.

Most kstat metrics best documentation is the kernel source code.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wall looking for.

_Most kstat metrics best documentation is the kernel source code._

That's what I was fearing